# How to enable Anydesk unattended access on headless Ubuntu machine?

Tags: headless, unattended-upgrades, anydesk

My company is subscribed to the Anydesk performance license, we hoped that there would be an option to create a custom client with unattended access available - however, there is not.

Now we are confused about how to enable Anydesk on a headless machine (meaning no one could physically accept the session request).

We easily managed to install it via terminal/PuTTY but now when we try to connect, there is no way to accept the request.

We also installed dummy drivers on the headless machine, so if we somehow managed to accept the session request, we would be able to see everything as if the machine had a display.

Keep in mind that these machines are far away from us, so plugging in the monitor is not an option.

Comment: You can configure AnyDesk using the command line, see https://support.anydesk.com/Command_Line_Interface